# useEffect почему то не делает setDisabled после завершения формы пока не сделаешь еще одно действие?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

```
useEffect(() => {
        const validate = () => {
            if (name.length === 0  || name ==='') {
                setErrors({...errors, name: true});
            } else {
                setErrors({...errors, name: false});
            }
            const emailCheckv2 = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            if (email.length < 1 || !emailCheckv2.test(email)) {
                setErrors({...errors, email: true});
            } else {
                setErrors({...errors, email: false});
            }
            if (password.length <= 5) {
                setErrors({...errors, password: true});
            } else {
                setErrors({...errors, password: false});
            }
            if (country === '') {
                setErrors({...errors, country: true});
            } else {
                setErrors({...errors, country: false});
            }
            if (gender === '') {
                setErrors({...errors, gender: true});
            } else {
                setErrors({...errors, gender: false});
            }
            console.log('agreement', agreement);
            if (!agreement) {
                setErrors({...errors, agreement: true});
            } else {
                setErrors({...errors, agreement: false});
            }

            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(errors)) {
                if(value || !key) {
                        setDisabled(true);
                        return false;
                    }
            }
            return true;
        };

        const check = validate();

        if(check && agreement) {
            setDisabled(false);
        }
        else {
            setDisabled(true);
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [name, email, password, gender, country, agreement, disabled]);
```

useEffect почему то не делает setDisabled после завершения формы пока не сделаешь еще одно действие?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот на картинке видно что не открывает кнопку пока не сделаешь еще изменения какого либо поля